# React lint warning react-hooks/exhaustive-deps on reading from state variable

Tags: reactjs

In an useEffect hook I access a state array length reading. This triggers react-hooks/exhaustive-deps in the linter. Why does this happen? The value of the variable is not modified here.

```
useEffect(() => {
    //... code processing search
    setHistoryList(history => [...history, search]); //adding latest search to history
    setHistPointer(history.length -1); //setting a pointer to the last history element
    //...
}, [search]);
```

Triggers Warning

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'history.length'
```

I don't think, that `history.legnth` is a dependency here, because it's value is not modified and thus doesn't need the hook to trigger nor any component using it rerendered.

This does not trigger the warning:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //... code processing search
    setHistoryList(history => [...history, search]); //adding latest search to history
    //setHistPointer(history.length -1); //setting a pointer to the last history element
    //...
}, [search]);
```

Comment: setHistPointer(history.length -1);
in this line, history is missing. Could you share the full code?

Comment: @PalashKantiBachar How is history missing there? No sorry, can't share the full code it's way too much to be posted fully in a question, it's a work in progress and not optimized yet. This is however the only line where history.length appears.

Comment: You are using the `history` and using the length, therefor it is a dependency. If it changes, the effect should rerun.

Comment: @Tikkes but it doesn't change.

Comment: All the better, if it doesn't change it will not re-trigger the effect. But anything you use coming from outside but part of the component is considered a dependency because the possibility of change is there. Whether or not it actually does, is not part of the question, the question is "Are we using is?". In your case, you are using history, therefor it is a dependency.

Comment: @Tikkes Funny enough at the point where I actually change `history`, it doesn't need to be a dependency (see edited post) but when I access it reading. Can't the linter just check if I access something reading or not?

Comment: @Supertyp No, it is a one of check on "use it or not". The linter is right though, it is a dependency of your effect. What you could do is add a check not to rerun it on change, but then I believe you should think about the design you did and perhaps, it doesn' t need to be an effect to begin with.

Comment: @Tikkes I wonder how else I could set a pointer to the id of the latest history element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204479/discussion-between-tikkes-and-supertyp).